# Thin web server: `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (RuntimeError) after git branch checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, thin

A Rails 3.2.0 app, working fine with Thin web server, both locally and on Heroku cedar stack.

After:

```
$ git branch work
$ git checkout work
$ rails server
```

I get:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
Exiting
/Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:572:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (RuntimeError)
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:572:in `start_server'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/tcp_server.rb:16:in `connect'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:53:in `block in start'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `call'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Also, when I do:

```
sudo bundle exec rails server thin -p 3000
```

I get:

```
/Users/peter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/peter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
from /Users/peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'
```

I have bundler 1.0.22 installed. Updated and installed it. Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you already have a server running elsewhere on the machine? Perhaps in Cucumber or something?

Comment: No, I haven't. Actually, restarting my computer had solved my problem. Today it happened again. Seems to happen when I switch over from one git branch to another.

Comment: Thanks! My error message on MacOSX was `... eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in \`start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)`.

Comment: Same for me when I tried to use the same port to run two different application. This topic just made me think about the other running application.

Answer (score 226):

This works for me. Find (zombie?) server (can happen when quitting terminal with server running):

```
$ ps ax | grep rails
```

If it returns something like:

```
33467 s002 S+ 0:00.00 grep rails
33240 s003 S+ 0:15.05 /Users/Arta/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby script/rails s -p 3000
```

kill it, and run anew:

```
$ kill -9 33240
$ rails s
```

Comment: If `ps ax | grep rails` doesn't turn up anything, try `ps ax | grep ruby`.

Comment: Definitely happens on OSX if you straight quit the terminal window while the rails server is running. +1

Answer (score 63):

The port 3000 may already be in use. Look at http://mrjaba.posterous.com/starttcpserver-no-acceptor-runtimeerror

Comment: From the above-linked article, a command to locate rails servers already running (works on mac):  `ps aux | grep rails`

Answer (score 48):

If there's any other process locking the port, you can find out which PID it has like this:

```
$ lsof -i :3000
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Passenger 40466 josh    5u  IPv4 0x7cae9332073ed4df      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
Passenger 40467 josh    5u  IPv4 0x7cae9332073ed4df      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

Then simply kill it/them:

```
$ kill -9 40466
$ kill -9 40467
```

Comment: `ntop` was using port 3000 on my machine. Answer is spot on.

Answer (score 47):

`pgrep ruby` to see what servers are running and then

```
kill -9 serverNumber
```

;)

Answer (score 8):

> rvmsudo rails server thin -p 3000

Does it for me

Answer (score 6):

I has this error because i was running [rails-dev-box](https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box) with Rails inside of it.

```
Port 3000 in the host computer is forwarded to port 3000 in the virtual machine. 
Thus, applications running in the virtual machine can be accessed via 
localhost:3000 in the host computer.
```

So is logged out from Vagrant and shutted down it:

```
vagrant@rails-dev-box:/vagrant/rails$ exit
$ vagrant halt
```

That helped me.

Comment: I had the same problem.  I had vagrant running from a separate project.  Probably not common, but it helped me.  Thanks! +1

Answer (score 5):

I had this error because I was already running rails in another terminal. Closing my other project fixed this.

Comment: If you want to run both programs at once, you can start your second server on a different port.

Comment: @Kevin great point. That wasn't was I trying to do, has just forgot that the other project was running.

Comment: @DJ That makes sense. I was posting my comment for future readers :)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue after getting back to the office from vacation. I run my server on the local IP as:

```
rails s thin -b <my_ip>
```

The problem was that my IP had changed, I just needed to use the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Execute this in the terminal

```
sudo netstat -lpn |grep rails
```

And then

```
sudo kill <job id>
```

Comment: This was the only way I was able to find my processes, though I had to grep for thin instead of rails.

Comment: Yes it works most of the cases. If you liked vote up please.

Comment: Finding and killing the process id did the trick. Though the first command didn't worked for me but `ps aux | grep rails`.