# ruby on rails 3 error running faye server with private_pub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, thin, faye, private-pub

I am trying to run the code from this tutorial : http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub

I downloaded the source from github and followed the instructions but then I run 
`rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production` the thin server doesn't start.

```
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
/home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:572:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (RuntimeError)
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:572:in `start_server'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/tcp_server.rb:16:in `connect'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:53:in `block in start'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `call'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:137:in `start'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rack-1.3.6/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/rackup:19:in `<main>'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605430/thin-web-server-start-tcp-server-no-acceptor-runtimeerror-after-git-branch

Comment: @Emrah Sorry, had forgotten to add the link.

Comment: @chrisbulmer I did have a look at that question before posting another one. However, I couldn't figure out what else was using that port.

Comment: Try ps ax | grep ruby then look for any other instances of Thin and kill them before trying again