# Converting rails project on sqlite3 on local host

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am new to rails and i am facing alot of problems while running the project on local host using mysql database .Is  there any way to run a project on sqlite3 on local host and on server it can be run using mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. In fact, I believe this setup is pretty common.

In your Gemfile, use `sqlite3` in the development group, and `mysql2` in the production group. For example,

```
group :production do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Then, on your development machine, use

```
$ gem install --without production
```

to avoid installing mysql. Finally, in `database.yml`, check that the sqlite adapter is selected for test and development, and the mysql adapter is selected for production.

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
```

This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I performed all the steps suggested by you and now on starting the server it is giving the error rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError) this please help.

Comment: You need to stop your previously running application server.

Comment: Tim there were no server running previously, I am not able to get why this error is arising each time i m trying to run the server.

Comment: server is running now refer this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605430/thin-web-server-start-tcp-server-no-acceptor-runtimeerror-after-git-branch)