# Unable to start the Rails Server using thin

Tags: ruby, thin, eventmachine, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I've a problem starting my rails server using the command `rails s`. I'm using thin as my web server. Whenever I try to start the rails server, thin starts listening on port 3000 and then it calls `eventmachine` gem to start a server by calling `start_tcp_server` which gives me the error that something is already running on port `3000` which is, of course, the thin server. I've tried so many solutions out there on internet but nothing seems to work for me. There are so many questions on Stackoverflow as well related to this problem but nothing solved my problem. Please have a look at this paste: http://chopapp.com/#mtvadchu

**UPDATE:**

There was a problem with my `/etc/hosts` file. I had some invalid characters in my file i.e.

```
ahi 127.0.0.1    localhost
```

so the `ahi` part was not valid. I just removed those characters and everything got fine. So if anyone else encounters this problem, just make sure that your `/etc/hosts` file is valid.

Comment: what happens if you call `rails s -p 4000` which will tell `thin` to run on port 4000 instead?

Comment: I get the same error, no matter which port I use. Because thin is sending the same port to eventmachine.

Comment: And you have tried this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605430/thin-web-server-start-tcp-server-no-acceptor-runtimeerror-after-git-branch)? And checked that `tmp/pids/server.pid` does not exist? Please show what you have tried so we can get those out of the way.

Comment: Yes, there are no files in `tmp/pids` folder. To be clear, I'm using RVM and I've another gemset for ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0 which is working fine. I just cloned the repository to another folder and upgraded the ruby and rails versions to 2.2.0 and 4.2 respectively. Now I'm unable to start the server in this new environment.
P.S: I've tried all the solutions from the provided question link.

Comment: Oh, I just missed one solution from that question and that very solution worked for me. Sorry for that but the solution for my problem is http://stackoverflow.com/a/20330258/1765499

I don't know why did this worked but it is....

Answer (score 0):

@KULKING, do one thing check whether your port 3000 is running or not by ->

$ **lsof -i tcp:3000**

****OR****

$ **lsof -i tcp**

If you think ruby is running previously on port 3000, kill that process by ->

$ kill -9 "pid"

And also checked that tmp/pids/server.pid does not exist?
if it is then please delete the server.pid

Comment: Hi, sorry that I didn't close the question but I already have solved it. The problem was with my `/etc/hosts` file. There were some characters before the local host mapping i.e. `ahi 127.0.0.1 localhost` which was the issue. I just removed `ahi` from the file and it started working :)