# Can't Start Rails Development,Cloud 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide, thin

I've tried to kill my rails server using this article from cloud 9.

I'm using the `gem thin` and everytime I try to run cloud server command I recieve this error

```
rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024  
Listening on 0.0.0.0:8080, CTRL+C to stop
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:530:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:530:in `start_server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/backends/tcp_server.rb:16:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thin-
```

[full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEhX6.png)

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605430/thin-web-server-start-tcp-server-no-acceptor-runtimeerror-after-git-branch

Comment: tried what this question suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the port 8080 is in use, to find the PID using the port, run :

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :8080
```

Then you can `kill -9 <PID>`

Answer (score 0):

This error says, 8080 port already in use, you may need to use different port for you application

**Update**:

Try to kill the existing process. Find port number using this command `ps -ef | grep thin` and then kill it `kill -9 <port>`. Try running your app now.

Comment: Rails Nuub here, how exactly does one do that ?

Comment: @leafshinobi25 Updated answer