# Rails server stops with 'no acceptor' error whenever I update files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, macos-sierra

While running a Rails dev server on `localhost:3000`, everything is running smoothly. In fact sometimes I can make changes to my code and save, and reload and everything is working well. However, without warning, I'll save changes to some files and when I go to load a page my server has stopped:

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:530:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:530:in `start_server'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/em-websocket-0.5.1/lib/em-websocket/websocket.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/react-rails-hot-loader-0.7.0/lib/hot_loader/server.rb:70:in `run_websocket_server'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/react-rails-hot-loader-0.7.0/lib/hot_loader/server.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:171:in `call'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:171:in `run'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/react-rails-hot-loader-0.7.0/lib/hot_loader/server.rb:36:in `block in start'
```

I have searched for this issue and the only related answer I have found was that there is another process that is running on the port: [Thin web server: `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (RuntimeError) after git branch checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605430/thin-web-server-start-tcp-server-no-acceptor-runtimeerror-after-git-branch)

I've followed the instructions but there are no other processes of Rails or anything on the port when I check.

This started happening around when I updated my OS. I'm currently running on MacOS Sierra 10.12.4 with Rails 4.2.8, hot loader 0.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Thin` as development server? There seems to be an incompatibility between the gem `react-rails-hot-reloader` and `Thin`, as reported on this issue (still open): https://github.com/rmosolgo/react-rails-hot-loader/issues/14. Of the comments point to a solution to this problem.